# ajax call to custom controller in Opencart Admin throws invalid token error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, opencart

The idea is to do something similar to add-to-cart inside the Admin Dashboard of Opencart 2.1.0.2.

I've written my AJAX script of add some content to the table on click of a button. But clicking on the button gives an alert with the below response. I tried everything I could and even looked up tens of links but I just can't seem to find let alone resolve the issue. I even tried including the token in the url but it just doesn't work.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Error Response

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
OK
```

The above is then followed by the HTML script of the login page that also contains the error message of invalid token.

Ajax script

```
var bucket = {
    'add': function(product_id, client_id, stylist_id) {
        console.log(product_id + " " + client_id + " " + stylist_id);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=stylist_dashboard/bucket/add',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                'product_id' : product_id,
                'client_id' : client_id,
                'stylist_id' : stylist_id
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {
                //$('.alert, .text-danger').remove();
                console.log('inside success');
                if (json['redirect']) {
                    location = json['redirect'];
                }

                if(json['success']) {
                    console.log(json['success']);
                },
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                   console.log(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
```

Controller

```
class ControllerStylistDashboardBucket extends Controller{
    public function add(){
        $this->log->debug('inside function add');

        $this->load->Model('stylist_dashboard/bucket');

        if (isset($this->request->post['product_id'])) {
            $product_id = (int)$this->request->post['product_id'];
        } else {
            $product_id = 0;
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['client_id'])) {
            $client_id = (int)$this->request->post['client_id'];
        } else {
            $client_id = 0;
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['stylist_id'])) {
            $stylist_id = (int)$this->request->post['stylist_id'];
        } else {
            $stylist_id = 0;
        }

        $this->log->debug($product_id,$client_id,$stylist_id);

        $bucket_id = $this->model_stylist_dashboard_bucket->add($product_id, $client_id, $stylist_id);

        //return $bucket_id;
        $json = array();
        $json['success'] = 'Successfully added to client bucket with Bucket Id: ' . $bucket_id;
        $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
    }
}
```

Model

```
class ModelStylistDashboardBucket extends Model{
    public function add($product_id, $client_id, $stylist_id){
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "customer_bucket (customer_id, stylist_id, product_id) VALUES ('" . $client_id . "','" . $stylist_id . "','" . $product_id . "')");

        $bucket_id = $this->db->getLastId();

        return $bucket_id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `contentType: "application/json",` in your code.

Example :

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=stylist_dashboard/bucket/add',
        contentType: "application/json",
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            'product_id' : product_id,
            'client_id' : client_id,
            'stylist_id' : stylist_id
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            //$('.alert, .text-danger').remove();
            console.log('inside success');
            if (json['redirect']) {
                location = json['redirect'];
            }

            if(json['success']) {
                console.log(json['success']);
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
               console.log(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In OC admin you have to include token in your url string.

Answer (score 0):

You must add token to your url string.

```
url: 'index.php?route=stylist_dashboard/bucket/add&token=<?php echo &token ?>',
```

and define it in your controller file

```
$data['token'] = $this->session->data['token'];
```